# Formatting in maven console

Tags: maven

Previously, maven output for my project yielded some slight colorization to easily see test run results, errors etc.  The other day it started producing some funky formatting that looked similar to:

1;34mINFO[m] on many lines.

I did some research and I see there was a recent maven release that actually added some more colorization.  I learned via a google search i can use 'mvn test -B' to remove the aforementioned formatting, but the output is black and white.  How do I configure it so that it runs in color per the samples videos I've seen online.

Comment: *How do I configure it so that it runs in color per the samples videos I've seen online.*  the videos aren't useful if you ask the question here again without trying out anything.

Comment: Not sure I follow you.  Forgot to mention I'm a novice at all this.  I'm a scrum master learning test automation because my team doesn't have QA :)

Comment: Please elaborate more in detail what you like to achieve and what you have tried so far...Furthermore where are you seeing such things..on console or in a jenkins log output or where?

Comment: I see these on the console from the cmd line in Windows.  I've learned I can use 'mvn test -B'. This removes the funky formatting and makes the output on the cmd readable.  However, it would be nice if the output could be colorized.  I'm not sure how to turn that 'on'.  Thank you.